# How do I assign values in one array to variable in another array

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to assign 1 to the variable `firstCol`, 2 to the variable `secondCol`...

When I begin looping through `colHeaders` the looping variable `Header` does not take on any value. I know the syntax is incorrect and `Header` is being assigned `num` but I felt this was the best way to explain what I'm trying to do.

Is it possible to loop through variables?

```
Dim colHeaders() As Variant
Dim Dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
Set Dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

colHeaders = Array(firstCol, secondCol, thirdCol, fourthCol, fifthCol)

num = 1
For Each Header In colHeaders
    Header = num
    num = num + 1
Next Header
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
Set Dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

Dim colHeaders() As Variant
colHeaders = Array("firstCol", "secondCol", "thirdCol", "fourthCol", "fifthCol")

Dim num As Long
num = 1

Dim header As Variant
For Each header In colHeaders
    Dict.Add header, num
    num = num + 1
Next header

Debug.Print Dict("secondCol")
```